# Change button color on 1st click and 2nd click revert to default

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create some buttons through java coding (already done this part). Then change the each and every button color on first click to GREEN and 2nd click to  gray or revert to default color. My code till now.

Java

```
        int number = 5; // number of buttons
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        myButton.setTag("hello " + i);
        myButton.setText("btn " + i);
        layout.addView(myButton);

    }

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int click = 1;

            if (click == 1) {
                myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                click = 0;
            } else {
                myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                click = 1;
            }

        }
    });
```

For now it's only changing the last button color to green (but not reverting to gray on 2nd click). Other buttons does not work.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You are changing the actual value of `myButton` in all iterations in the for loop, thus the button it points to is always the fifth one. That's the button which has the onClickListener set.

Comment: @user221256 Then can you suggest what the possible solution can be? I am new to android. So, all the concepts are not clear to me.

Comment: Instead of handling like above, You can create a custom button with three statu, that makes your job so easy. For further reference you follow the link below
http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.in/2014/06/making-three-state-custom-button-in.html

Comment: @Rahul Please follow the below answer

Comment: @Rahul Just create a onClickListener field as you have in your code and set it inside the loop.

Comment: @user221256 Tried your suggestion just now. Now the problem is, no matter which button I click, always the last button color changes.

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake.. I think the simplest and most elegant solution is to create your own two state button

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't create buttons in a loop like that using the same name. In the end you'll have reference to just one button. You need to create them separately.

Second, in your `onClick()`, you set the value of click to equal 1 every time you click the button. As a result you will always be setting the background color to green.

This is what you should do:

```
int number = 5; // number of buttons
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);

boolean myButtonIsClicked1 = false;   // used to check if button has been clicked

myButton1 = new Button(this);
myButton1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
myButton1.setTag("hello 1");
myButton1.setText("btn 1");
layout.addView(myButton1);
```

and do the same for the other 4 buttons

Now you will need to set a listener for each button. So here will be button 1's listener:

```
myButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // You can't have int click = 1 here anymore
        // int click = 1;

        if (myButtonIsClicked1) {
            myButton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            myButtonIsClicked1 = false;
        } else {
            myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            myButtonIsClicked1 = true;
        }
    }
});
```

and follow the same pattern for the other 4 buttons.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. but the thing is I need to create the buttons using loop. since I don't have fixed number of button. for testing purpose I have set it to 5. it can be 5 or 10 or 20.

Comment: You need to rethink your entire code structure then. You should be using a `ListView` with a custom Adapter. This makes it very easy to add rows containing `Buttons`, `TextView`s, etc. Just google that and you should find some good resources like this one: https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd

Answer (score 0):

its quite easy I guess you just have to store the state somewhere and best place will be the view itself.

sample code:

```
button.onClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View view){
     if(view.getTag()==null){
       //first time set color to green
       view.setTag("green");
       view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
     }else if(view.getTag().toString().equals("green")){
       //green color already set change to grey
       view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);
     }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You'll need to do two things.

First of all, create a new `button_background.xml` file. Inside, put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then set that drawable as the background on your button in the XML for your layout.

Inside your java file, do the following:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
myButton.setTag("hello " + i);
myButton.setText("btn " + i);
layout.addView(myButton);

}

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());

    }
});
```

This sets the background of the button based on whether or not the button is activated. When the button is pressed, the activated state is flipped.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: error in **state_activated="true"**. screenshot provided...

https://imgur.com/SH60CW8

Comment: @Rahul My mistake. I forgot to add the "android" namespace. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No response when I click on the buttons. I think because button_background.xml is not used anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Rahul I told you to set it as the background for your button. After you create the button, call `myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background.xml))`

Comment: thanks for the reply. it's working properly but only the last button. BTN 4 is working perfectly. but when i click on the other buttons nothing happens.

Comment: if possible, pls do help me.

Comment: You're overwriting `myButton` every time you go through your loop, so naturally when you get to the end, you'd only have the last one available to you. If I were you, I would put your buttons in a layout with different IDs, then you can reference each one individually. If you're determined to do it this way, create one OnClickListener above your loop, and set it as the listener for each button inside your loop. Then in `onClick` you can determine which button you're referencing and react accordingly.